# Is there a Python function that finds an unknown inside an integral?

Tags: python, math, scipy, numeric

I have a integral with unknown `h`. My integral looks like this

[image]

where C, a, b are constants F(x) and G(x) are two functions. So the only unknows in the integral is h. How can I solve it ? I guess I need to use scipy but I dont know how to implement or use which functions.

I need to find the value of the h

Thanks

Comment: Evaluate the integral and then solve for `h` algebraically.

Comment: It cannot be evaluated by hand. The F and G functions are too complex to do it by hand

Comment: Have you tried a symbolic solver like Wolfram Alpha? You could certainly brute-force the solution by varying `h` and using `scipy` to integrate with different values for `h` until you get the area `C`.

Comment: Thats a good idea..never thought it before.I can set some error and then brute force.

Comment: Take a look at Sympy (https://sympy.org). I'm pretty sure Sympy will be able to find the list of free parameters in the integrand, and then you compare that to a list of known values to find any others. But maybe you should clarify what goal you want to reach. Do you just need to identify h as a free parameter? or do you mean to solve C = integral(...) for h, so that you have h as a function of C? or something else? Please add any additional information to the problem statement, instead of responding to this comment.

Comment: @RobertDodier I just need to find the value of the h

Comment: `scipy` has integration functions as well as solvers.  A numeric solver would start with a initial `h` guess, call the integrator (over `x`) with all variables fixed (including `h`), and then repeatedly vary `h` to the integrate result is solved.  I don't expect it to be fast, since both the solver and the integrator will iterate (and call your complex `F` and `G`.

Comment: @hpaulj I need some example code. If I know those things I wouldnt ask here..

Comment: SO is better suited for debugging help than providing solutions from scratch.